# How to detect when keyboard is opened or closed in React Native

Tags: react-native

How to detect if user close the keyboard in react native, I want to call a function when user closed the keyboard.

and if you can answer to detect keyboard is open too it will be appreciated, thanks.

I'm on the react native latest `version 0.56`

Answer (score 122, accepted):

#### 1. You can use **[Keyboard class](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboard)** from facebook.

Here is a sample code.

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Keyboard, TextInput } from 'react-native';

class Example extends Component {
  componentWillMount () {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow);
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide);
  }
    
  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
  }
    
  _keyboardDidShow () {
    alert('Keyboard Shown');
  }
    
  _keyboardDidHide () {
    alert('Keyboard Hidden');
  }
    
  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

###2. You can use some other npm dependency also, like **[react-native-keyboard-listener](https://github.com/alexmngn/react-native-keyboard-listener#readme)**.

Import the component into the file you want to use it:

```js
import KeyboardListener from 'react-native-keyboard-listener';
```

Use the component directly in your code. The component won't render anything

```js
<View>
  <KeyboardListener
    onWillShow={() => { this.setState({ keyboardOpen: true }); }}
    onWillHide={() => { this.setState({ keyboardOpen: false }); }}
  />
</View>
```

To install this dependency run below command.

```
npm install --save react-native-keyboard-listener
```

**Choose any you feel more convenient.**

Comment: the first one i wanted that its works like a superman :D thanks man.

Comment: @Khemraj why i can't setState in function _keyboardDidShow or _keyboardDidHide?

Comment: @Khemraj It should be noted that option 2 is no longer working on android

Comment: I added `Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', alert('keyboard'));` to my app and it fires as soon as I open it. It's the same both in web view and on my Android device. Any ideas what I am doing wrong?

Comment: @stefanS yes. `alert('keyboard')` is being executed at the moment you bind the handler. to fire the alert when the handler is triggered, use `Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', () => alert('keyboard'));`

Comment: Info aditional:
this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow.bind(this));

Use  .bind(this)   in order to can use setState or this

Answer (score 206):

Thank you guys for your answers. Here is the hooks version if someone is interested:

```js
const [isKeyboardVisible, setKeyboardVisible] = useState(false);

 useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      () => {
        setKeyboardVisible(true); // or some other action
      }
    );
    const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidHide',
      () => {
        setKeyboardVisible(false); // or some other action
      }
    );

    return () => {
      keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
      keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);
```

Comment: Hi @5-10. I've used this exact code in my App but for some reason neither of the events is fired. I'm using RN version 0.63.4 with  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the manifest file. What could possibly cause it to not function properly? Thanks.

Comment: works as expected on RN 0.63.4 without any manifest changes.

Comment: when I try this I get the following Error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: useEffect`, any reason for this?

Comment: a little bit late but @yem you need to: `import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react"` and also `import { Keyboard } from "react-native"`

Answer (score 23):

I wrapped this up in a hook:

```
import { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { Keyboard } from 'react-native';

export const useKeyboardVisible = () => {
    const [isKeyboardVisible, setKeyboardVisible] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
            'keyboardDidShow',
            () => {
                setKeyboardVisible(true);
            },
        );
        const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
            'keyboardDidHide',
            () => {
                setKeyboardVisible(false);
            },
        );

        return () => {
            keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
            keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
        };
    }, []);

    return isKeyboardVisible;
};
```

The hook returns a boolean flag that can be used to apply logic conditionally or run any other effect needed.

Comment: Thanks this is a great answer - thank you!. One small modification that worked better for me was using keyboardWillShow and keyboardWillHide events instead. These events fire when the keyboard WILL appear so it gives time to, for instance, move a text input at the same time as the keyboard is loading.

Comment: Thanks for commenting mate! 

Yeah, that makes sense, you might have two different hooks for covering different scenarios in your app: useKeyboardDidShow useKeyboardWillShow could be a good naming for them

Comment: Oh yeah that's a great idea!

Comment: This is a really convenient solution - thanks @halbano!

Comment: PLEASE NOTE: to use this as a hook in your React or React Native Apps, ```import { useKeyboardVisible } from "../../useKeyboardVisible";``` then ```const isKeyboardVisible = useKeyboardVisible();``` if you ```console.log(isKeyboardVisible)``` you'll get your ```"true"``` or ```"false"``` state.

Comment: works like a charm

Answer (score 17):

### 2023 Update

If you are using React native 0.71 or later you can use `Keyboard.isVisible()`

Example

```
import {Keyboard, Text, TextInput, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';

const Example = () => {
  return (
    <View style={style.container}>
      <TextInput
        style={style.input}
        placeholder="Click here…"
        onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
      />
      
      {Keyboard.isVisible() && <Text>Keyboard is visible</Text>}
    </View>
  );
};

const style = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    padding: 36,
  },
  input: {
    padding: 10,
    borderWidth: 0.5,
    borderRadius: 4,
  },
});

export default Example;
```

Comment: Great answer. Thank you, much less coding than setting up events/listeners

Answer (score 9):

I came across the [usekeyboard](https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks#usekeyboard) hook found in [@react-native-community/hooks](https://github.com/react-native-community)

E.g.

```
import { useKeyboard } from '@react-native-community/hooks'

const keyboard = useKeyboard()

console.log('keyboard isKeyboardShow: ', keyboard.keyboardShown)
console.log('keyboard keyboardHeight: ', keyboard.keyboardHeight)
```

Source: https://github.com/react-native-community/hooks/blob/master/src/useKeyboard.ts

Comment: Good solution but there appears to be a delay in getting the current keyboard state

Answer (score 8):

Improved version of @Khemraj 's answer (which worked great for me) with **bound methods to the instance in order to be able to update the component's state** from the listener and re-render.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Keyboard, TextInput } from 'react-native';

class Example extends Component {

  state = {
      keyboardState: 'closed'
  }

  componentWillMount () {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow);
    this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide);
  }

  componentWillUnmount () {
    this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
  }

  _keyboardDidShow = () => {
    this.setState({
        keyboardState: 'opened'
    });
  }

  _keyboardDidHide = () => {
    this.setState({
        keyboardState: 'closed'
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
        onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
      />
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I used a small remix to the great answer from @halbano that may be useful to consider depending on your situation

```js
export default function useKeyboardOffsetHeight(): number {
  const [keyBoardOffsetHeight, setKeyboardOffsetHeight] = useState(0);

  useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardWillShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardWillShow",
      (e) => {
        setKeyboardOffsetHeight(e.endCoordinates.height);
      }
    );
    const keyboardWillHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardWillHide",
      () => {
        setKeyboardOffsetHeight(0);
      }
    );

    return () => {
      keyboardWillHideListener.remove();
      keyboardWillShowListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return keyBoardOffsetHeight;
}
```

### `keyBoardOffsetHeight` vs `isKeyboardVisible`

I used integer `keyBoardOffsetHeight` instead of boolean `isKeyboardVisible` . Since it's often useful to move some of your other components based on the keyboard size. The offset is either 0 (hidden) or Y > 0 pixels (it is shown). Then I can use that in styling like so:

```js
  const keyBoardOffsetHeight = useKeyboardOffsetHeight();
...
    <View
      style={{
        bottom: keyBoardOffsetHeight,
      }}
    >
```

### `keyboardWillShow` vs `keyboardDidShow`

Secondly, I use `keyboardWillShow` events so that I can anticipate the keyboard appearing and fire my UI changes earlier.

The `keyboardDidShow` event fires once the keyboard has already appeared.

I also used `keyboardWillHide` instead of `keyboardDidHide` based on the same reasoning.

Comment: keyboardWillShow did not have the height for me. Had to use keyboardDidShow.
WillShow is the intent/action;  DidShow would have the result of the action.

Comment: If you are building something for Android this will not work. keyboardDidShow and keyboardDidHide only are available on Android.

Comment: My typescript installation doesn't provide the remove methods. However they work.

Answer (score 1):

MobX version:

```js
import { observable } from 'mobx'
import { EmitterSubscription, Keyboard } from 'react-native'

class KeyboardStore {
  @observable isKeyboardVisible = false
  keyboardSubs: EmitterSubscription[] = []

  subKeyboard() {
    this.keyboardSubs = [
      Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', () => this.isKeyboardVisible = true),
      Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', () => this.isKeyboardVisible = false),
    ]
  }

  unsubKeyboard() {
    this.keyboardSubs.forEach(sub => sub.remove())
    this.keyboardSubs = []
  }
}
```

and inside top level App component

```js
  useEffect(() => {
    store.subKeyboard()
    return () => {
      store.unsubKeyboard()
    }
  }, [])
```

and check anywhere in your app with `store.isKeyboardVisible`.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's more simpler than using useEffect or other stuff. TextInput provides methods onFocus and onBlur.

```
import {TextInput} from "react-native";

const [isKeyboardVisible, setIsKeyboardVisible] = useState(false);

<TextInput 
  value={someValue}
  onFocus={() => setIsKeyboardVisible(true}
  onBlur={() => setIsKeyboardVisible(false}
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

All the thing already avalable in react-native `Keyboard` class

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Keyboard, TextInput } from 'react-native';

class Example extends Component {

    componentDidMount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidShow', this._keyboardDidShow);
        this.keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardDidHide', this._keyboardDidHide);
        this.keyboardWillShowListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillShow', this._keyboardWillShow);
        this.keyboardWillHideListener = Keyboard.addListener('keyboardWillHide', this._keyboardWillHide);
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        this.keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
        this.keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
        this.keyboardWillShowListener.remove();
        this.keyboardWillHideListener.remove();
    }

    _keyboardWillShow() {
        console.log('Keyboard Showning')
    }

    _keyboardWillHide() {
        console.log('Keyboard Heding')
    }

    _keyboardDidShow() {
        alert('Keyboard Shown');
    }

    _keyboardDidHide() {
        alert('Keyboard Hidden');
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <TextInput
                onSubmitEditing={Keyboard.dismiss}
            />
        );
    }
}
```