# Unable to close the opened searchable dropdown on back button click

Tags: react-native, dropdown, searchable-dropdown

I am using searchable drop-down using the below module.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-searchable-dropdown

When the drop-down is open, when I click on back button the drop-down does not close. And until I select any option it will be opened only. How to resolve this?

```
<View style={{ marginTop: 5 }}>
    <SearchableDropdown
        onItemSelect={(item, index) => {
            setItemname(item.value);
            setItemIndex(index);
        }}
        itemStyle={{
            padding: 10,
            marginTop: 2,
            backgroundColor: '#ddd',
            borderColor: '#bbb',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderRadius: 5,
        }}
        itemTextStyle={{ color: '#222' }}
        itemsContainerStyle={{ maxHeight: 140 }}
        items={items}
        defaultIndex={itemindex}
        resetValue={false}
        textInputProps={
            {
                placeholder: "Select Item",
                underlineColorAndroid: "transparent",
                style: {
                    padding: 12,
                    borderWidth: 1,
                    borderColor: '#ccc',
                    borderRadius: 5,
                },
            }
        }
        listProps={{
            nestedScrollEnabled: true,
        }}
    />
</View>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### What is happening

The `SearchableDropDown` component uses `TextInput`'s `onBlur` prop to set its `focus` state to `false` on blur ([code reference](https://github.com/zubairpaizer/react-native-searchable-dropdown/blob/master/index.js#L175)).

When the `focus` state is `true` the `FlatList` is rendered that contains the items ([code reference](https://github.com/zubairpaizer/react-native-searchable-dropdown/blob/master/index.js#L30)).

The problem is that when you press the back button `onBlur` is not triggered, meaning the `focus` state is not set to `false` and the `FlatList` with the items is still rendered.

---

#### Possible workaround

You could conditionally hide the flatlist based on whether the keyboard is hidden or not.

```
import React, { Component, useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { View, TextInput, Keyboard } from "react-native";
import SearchableDropdown from "react-native-searchable-dropdown";

const App = () => {
  const [itemname, setItemname] = useState("");
  const [itemindex, setItemIndex] = useState(0);
  const [isKeyboardVisible, setKeyboardVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardDidShow",
      () => {
        setKeyboardVisible(true);
      }
    );
    const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      "keyboardDidHide",
      () => {
        setKeyboardVisible(false);
      }
    );

    return () => {
      keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
      keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <View style={{ marginTop: 5 }}>
      <SearchableDropdown
        onItemSelect={(item, index) => {
          setItemname(item.value);
          setItemIndex(index);
        }}
        itemStyle={{
          padding: 10,
          marginTop: 2,
          backgroundColor: "#ddd",
          borderColor: "#bbb",
          borderWidth: 1,
          borderRadius: 5,
        }}
        itemTextStyle={{ color: "#222" }}
        itemsContainerStyle={
          isKeyboardVisible ? { maxHeight: 140 } : { display: "none" }
        }
        items={items}
        defaultIndex={itemindex}
        resetValue={false}
        textInputProps={{
          placeholder: "Select Item",
          underlineColorAndroid: "transparent",
          style: {
            padding: 12,
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: "#ccc",
            borderRadius: 5,
          },
        }}
        listProps={{
          nestedScrollEnabled: true,
        }}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

export default App;
```

The implementation above sets `itemsContainerStyle` to an object with `display` set to `'none'` when the `isKeyboardVisible` state is `false`.

---

[Source used for hiding/showing keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57502759/9098350)