# How to identify that the keyboard is open or not in react native?

Tags: react-native, keyboard-events

I have text input and a submit button, I added event on text input of "onendediting", if I put value in textbox and press on submit button without end the editing so the event "onendediting" is not fired as expected. so I want to track the keyboard if keyboard is on I don't allow to submit button to work.
How can I handle this ? I used "keyboard.addEventListener" but it wont work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect when keyboard is opened or closed in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51606099/how-to-detect-when-keyboard-is-opened-or-closed-in-react-native)

Answer (score 3):

**NOTE FOR ANDROID:** If your Manifest file contains `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"` the hook will not work on Android.

I use a hook for this:

```js
import {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {Keyboard} from 'react-native';

const useKeyboard = () => {
  const [isKeyboardVisible, setKeyboardVisible] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    const keyboardDidShowListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidShow',
      () => {
        setKeyboardVisible(true);
      },
    );

    const keyboardDidHideListener = Keyboard.addListener(
      'keyboardDidHide',
      () => {
        setKeyboardVisible(false);
      },
    );

    return () => {
      keyboardDidHideListener.remove();
      keyboardDidShowListener.remove();
    };
  }, []);

  return isKeyboardVisible;
};

export default useKeyboard;
```

Usage:

```js
import React from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import useKeyboard from './useKeyboard';

const App = () => {
  const isKeyboardOpen = useKeyboard();

  return isKeyboardOpen ? <Text>OPEN</Text> : <Text>CLOSE</Text>;
};
```

Comment: The above example is not working in my case. My Manifest file contain android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize".