# Callback when Keyobard is fully closed in react native android?

Tags: android, react-native, keyboard, android-softkeyboard, keyboard-events

I want to know the event/callback function in React Native Android when Keyboard is closed not when the keyboard is about to close. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to detect when keyboard is opened or closed in React Native](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51606099/how-to-detect-when-keyboard-is-opened-or-closed-in-react-native)

Comment: @user18309290 The above answer works only when the method is called to dismiss the keyboard. The keyboard hides asynchronous so it takes around 300-400 milliseconds. so the above question did not work for me. thanks. I hope you will understand my situation.